# Assembly, ld cannot find _start;

Tags: assembly

I have recently been trying to learn about assembly and I have an assembly file that begins:

```
global _start
_start:
```

Which throws an error when attempting to link with:

> ld -o assemblyCode assembly.o -g

The error is:

> ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start;

I have also tried appending a few other commands to the start of the asm file such as:

```
section .text
segment .text
```

All produce the same results. I would like to know what I am doing wrong with this such that the linker cant see the _start: command?

This is running on Ubuntu, using nasm to build the assembly file.

Comment: Were you planning to assemble the assembly file to an object file?

Comment: I was using "nasm -f elf assembly.asm -g" to build It into an elf file and then the above ld command to link it.

Comment: nasm will create a .o file, use "ld -o assembly assembly.o" to link

Comment: Apologies about this, I have written that out wrong, I am using the assembly.o file in the ld command, the .asm file is in the nasm command.

Comment: What output do you get from `nm assembly.o`? Do you see your `_start` there? Please post [MCVE]. Also, if you are on a 64 bit OS, use `ld -melf_i386` (although in that case you should have gotten a different error about incompatible architecture).

Comment: 00000000 t global _start
00000000 t _start:   There is obviously a newline between these but it doesn't seem to be formatting all that well in comments

Comment: That means you have done something wrong with `global _start` because it has been exported as a symbol. Also `_start:` has been exported including the trailing colon.  Make sure you have a proper space between the two words. Better delete the whole line and retype it from scratch. If problem persists, paste the **exact** source file you are using along with the exact `nasm` command.

Comment: Any chance you actually used `global _start:` rather than `global _start` (the colon needs to be removed if you have it)

Comment: @John: That's not an error, it's a warning.  Then `ld` picks the start of the text segment (or section?) as the entry point.  In a program like this, that works, too.  And BTW, SO doesn't let you format comments.  That's why if you have additional info that people asked for in comments, you should post it in the question as edit.

Comment: Looks like you left out the space and declared a symbol called `global_start`.  But that's not what you showed in your question.  **always copy/paste code into SO, especially when you don't understand why it doesn't work**.  Downvoted for lack of [mcve].  The code in the question assembles + links with no warning for me with `yasm -felf64 -Worphan-labels -gdwarf2 link.asm && ld -o link link.o` (using my usual `asm-link` script which runs that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hard do tell without seeing the whole code

here's a very small program, that you can use as skeleton:

```
section .text
        global _start       ;must be declared for using gcc
_start:                     ;tell linker entry point
        mov     edx, len    ;message length
        mov     ecx, msg    ;message to write
        mov     ebx, 1      ;fd to use is stdout
        mov     eax, 4      ;sys_write
        int     0x80        ;call kernel
        mov     eax, 1      ;sys_exit
        int     0x80        ;call kernel

section .data

msg     db      'Hello, stack overflow!',0xa     ; say hello to the guys
len     equ     $ - msg                          ;length of the string
```

to assemble (into an object file) use `nasm -g -f elf sample.s`

to link `ld -o sample sample.o`